# Kinetic JS shape shadows get more visible when adding another shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

First, I'm required to use version kinetic-v4.3.3 due to a group dragging (known) bug in the latest version.

So I have a kinetic structure as follows:

```
ShapesGroup    
 ShapeGroup
  Circle
  Text
```

And on 'mouseenter' on either text or circle, a tool tip is displayed and we add the ToolTipGroup to the structure. On 'mouseout' the ToolTipGroup is destroyed.

```
ShapesGroup  
 ShapeGroup
  Circle
  Text
  ToolTipGroup
   Rectangle
   Text
```

Currently each shape and text object has shadows enabled. Now, whenever the ToolTipGroup is added, it seems that all the shadow enabled objects inside ShapesGroup (the container of all the ShapeGroups), have their shadow properties modified somehow so that they appear to get more 'bold'.

Here are a couple of screen shots : focus on the yellow banana shaped area ^_^

[image: Before picture with normal shadows.]
[image: After picture with more bold shadows.]

You should be able to easily see that all the shadows within the ShapesGroup are much 'stronger'.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Robodude/LxhLX/3/
It's really easy to notice whenever you hover over a circle/text.

The [calendar.js](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/938212/calendar.js) file is pretty huge, so here's some relevant code.

This is the method that creates the tooltip kinetic object.

```
Day.prototype.createDataToolTip = function (data, target, xOffset, yOffset) {
    var month = this.parent;
    var year = month.parent;
    var calendar = year.parent;

    var stagePos = calendar.stage.getPosition();
    var mousePos = calendar.stage.getMousePosition();
    var bgLayerPos = calendar.stage.get(".bgCalendarLayer")[0].getPosition();
    var dataPos = calendar.stage.get(".dataGroup")[0].getPosition();
    var targetPos = target.getPosition();
    var parentPos = target.parent.getPosition();
    var width = target.getWidth();
    var height = target.getWidth();


    var widthMultiplier = 5;
    var newW = calendar.dayWidth * widthMultiplier;

    var alreadyDisplayed = target.parent.get(".toolTipGroup_" + data.Id)[0];

    if (alreadyDisplayed == null) {
        var padding = 6;
        var tooltipText = new Kinetic.Text({
            text: data.HoverText,
            x: padding,
            y: padding,
            //height:(calendar.dayHeight * 4) - padding,
            width: (calendar.dayWidth * widthMultiplier) - (padding * 2),
            align: "left",
            fontSize: 12,
            fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
            fontStyle: 'bold',
            fill: 'white',
            //shadowColor: 'black',
            id: "tooltipText_" + data.Id,
            name: "tooltipText_" + data.Id
        });

        var th = tooltipText.getHeight();

        var tooltipBG = new Kinetic.Rect({
            height: th + (padding / 2) + tooltipText.getFontSize(),
            width: calendar.dayWidth * widthMultiplier,
            //fill: data.Color,
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            fillLinearGradientStartPoint: [-50, -50],
            fillLinearGradientEndPoint: [50, 50],
            fillLinearGradientColorStops: [0, 'white', 1, data.Color],
            name: "toolTipBG_" + data.Id,
            id: "toolTipBG_" + data.Id,
            shadowColor: 'black',
            shadowBlur: 10,
            shadowOffset: 5,
            shadowOpacity: .5
        });

        var newX = 0 - (newW / 2);
        var newY = yOffset + 1;

        if (parentPos.y > calendar.stage.getHeight() / 2) // if the shape is in bottom half of the screen
        {
            newX = 0 - (newW / 2);
            newY = -yOffset - 1 - tooltipBG.getHeight();
        }


        var tooltipGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
            x: newX,
            y: newY,
            name: "toolTipGroup_" + data.Id,
            id: "toolTipGroup_" + data.Id
        });


        tooltipGroup.add(tooltipBG);
        tooltipGroup.add(tooltipText);

        target.parent.add(tooltipGroup);

        target.parent.draw();
        console.log(target.parent);
    }


}
```

This is the event handler for the 'mouseenter' on the circles:

```
dataCircle.on("mouseenter", function () {
    this.parent.moveToTop();
    if (calendar.miniMap != false) {
        var parent = this.parent;
        var text = parent.get(".dataCircleText_" + data.Id)[0];
        text.moveToTop();
        day.createDataToolTip(data, this, this.attrs.radius, this.attrs.radius);
    }
    dg.draw();
});
```

Any ideas why this is happening? It seems so unrelated and unexpected that I'm not sure what's going on.

Thanks for reading :)

EDIT: Since the draggable bug which 'forces' me into using an older version of kinetic, I tried using the latest version and this is what happens on hover:

[image: On hover with the latest version of kinetic]

As you can see, the shadow problem doesn't seem to be an issue here - but something else is totally wrong -_-;;

Comment: I have never used KineticJS but here is an idea that you might want to check out if you didn't already. Make sure your "circles with shadow" aren't getting redrawn again when your event happens. It sure looks like shadow in second example is just duplicated one from first example. I really don't know `Kinetic` as I said, but there must be a way to "clear" everything and redraw it again. Try to force it when event occurs and if that fixes it you found your problem source.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did a quick test to see what would happen if I removed the 'remove tool tip' on mouseout and I think your suspicion  might be the cause of this issue because the shadow kept getting darker and darker anytime I entered a circle shape.

Comment: Actually, working through it I noticed I had a 'dg.draw();' in my mouseenter event handler. Removing that 'extra' draw, essentially solved the issue. If you submit an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: heh, great that you've found out the source :) Ok, will copy/paste comment tho it's far from exact and good answer but I guess it maybe helped you to find root of the problem a bit faster.

Comment: oh my, that's a very old version.  Can you explain what the group drag bug is?  It may have been fixed by v4.5.1

Comment: @EricRowell After beginning development of this project with the latest version of kinetic, I came across this same bug: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/404
I started going backwards with versions until the bug wasn't occurring and that's why I'm using 4.3.3

Comment: Oh! You're the guy! I'm geek 'star struck' right now :D Thanks for kinetic and the site, it's awesome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used KineticJS but here is an idea that you might want to check out if you didn't already. Make sure your "circles with shadow" aren't getting redrawn again when your event happens. It sure looks like shadow in second example is just duplicated one from first example. I really don't know Kinetic as I said, but there must be a way to "clear" everything and redraw it again. Try to force it when event occurs and if that fixes it you found your problem source.

Comment: You're right! That entire group was being drawn twice causing the shadows to stack. I removed the dg.draw() from the 'mouseenter' event handler and it responds as I would expect.